# Use switch-case construction to count how many times a number has been typed

Tags: c, character-encoding

Create a C-program that counts how many times each of the numbers `0-4` have been typed. Use a `switch`-`case` construction. Use `default` to count the number of other characters. Print the amount of times a certain number has been typed.

Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    int num_0 = 0;
    int num_1 = 0;
    int num_2 = 0;
    int num_3 = 0;
    int num_4 = 0;
    int num_other = 0;
    printf("Input something\n");

    while ((a = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        switch (a)
        {
        case 0:
            num_0++;break;
        case 1:
            num_1++;break;
        case 2:
            num_2++;break;
        case 3:
            num_3++;break;
        case 4:
            num_4++;break;
        default:
            num_other++;break;
        };

    }
    printf("0 has been typed %d", num_0);printf(" times\n");
    printf("1 has been typed %d", num_1);printf(" times\n");
    printf("2 has been typed %d", num_2);printf(" times\n");
    printf("3 has been typed %d", num_3);printf(" times\n");
    printf("4 has been typed %d", num_4);printf(" times\n");
    printf("other characters have been typed %d", num_other);printf(" times\n");

    return 0;
}
```

No matter what I input, all the numbers including `0,1,2,3,4` were counted as other characters. Could someone tell me why my code didn't work.

Comment: I am not good at switch-case construction, maybe something wrong with it

Comment: For example, if I input 123450, the expected result should be "0 has been typed 1 time, 1 has been typed 1 time etc". But what I really saw is "0 has been typed 0 time, 1 has been typed 0 time. Other characters have been typed 6 times"

Comment: Note that you _could_ replace this whole thing with `int num[5] = {0};

for (int a=getchar(); a>='0' && a='4'; a=getchar())
{
  num[a-'0']++;
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`switch (a)` will compare the code of `a`. If you typed digits, it should be;

```
    case '0':
        num_0++;break;
    case '1':
        num_1++;break;
  ...
```

switch on *character values* not integers (int value of `0` is not 0, for example in ASCII it is 48, but let's not use the value directly, so it's fully portable)

Maybe a better thing to do would be to create a table instead:

```
int count[10] = {0};

....
a -= '0';  // removes the offset
if ((a >= 0) && (a < 10))  // check bounds
{
    count[a]++;
}
```

Comment: thanks. `a` is an integer. '0' literal is also an integer, so why UB?

Comment: The same feeling - when you spend whole day trying to find out that  extra semicolon you missed. @Bathsheba what say? Wish speed. :D

Comment: My mistake. It's always safe to subtract a `char` from any other `char`. (Both are promoted to `int`, and things like `'0'` are `int` types in C anyway.

Comment: Using a switch construct seems to be part of the assigment. Also counting other characters shall be done. Therefore your second variant probably does not qualify for a soluation.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is in [man getchar](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar) (*emphasis mine*)

> `fgetc()` reads the next character from stream and **returns it as an `unsigned char` cast to an `int`, or `EOF` on end of file or error.**
>
> `getc()` is equivalent to `fgetc()` except that it may be implemented as a macro which evaluates stream more than once.
>
> `getchar()` is equivalent to `getc(stdin)`.

After that, the ***numerical representation*** of a character need not be the same as the character value (and mostly, is not), i.e., a character `0` (`'0'`) does not have the numerical value of `0`, [in ASCII encoding](http://www.asciitable.com/), it has a decimal value of `48`.

So, to count a character `'0'`, you should set the `case` values to `'0'`, not `0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = getchar()
```

When you are reading characters, the value gets stored in variable is the ASCII value. When you type 1 the value getting stored in a is 49.

```
switch (a)
{
    case 1:
    num_0++;
    break;
}
```

In this code you are comparing with ASCII value 49(ASCII value for 1) with ASCII value 1 and comparison return false. 
Similarly all the conditions give false and goes to default case.

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistake in your code .

1) You are taking input through getchar() function , so it takes character in the input .

2) Take the input variable 'a' as char not int .

3) Mark single quotes in case options like case '1' because you are taking input as a character so you must mark single quotes .